# Inverse integral with substitution

Tags: integration

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{du}{1+u^2}$$

How do i perform integration for inverse function that have a function within it? do I have to perform another substitution? thanks.

Comment: $(\arctan x)'=1/(1 + x^2)$.

Comment: thankyou! did not thought of it

Answer (score 2):

The answer is immediate $$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{du}{1+u^2}=\arctan(u)+\mathcal C$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you don't know this result, you can derive it knowing basic trigonometric properties and the facts that 
$$\int x^{n}dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} +c$$
where $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $n\ne -1$.
and
$$\frac{d(\tan\theta)}{d\theta}=\sec^2\theta$$

Then, in
$$\int\frac1{1+u^2}du$$
Let $u=\tan \theta$. Then $du=\sec^2\theta d\theta$
$$\int\frac1{1+u^2}du=\int\frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}d\theta=\int\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}d\theta=\int d\theta = \theta +c =\arctan u +c$$

Comment: If the asker cannot recognize the derivative of the arctangent function, I think it wouldn't be easy for him to come up with that substitution. In my opinion, this should be an immediate integral by identifying the derivative of an elementary function.

Comment: @Joanpemo Agreed, but nevertheless, it is quite possible that the identity $1+\tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta$ is known without knowing the above result. One can always try it out to simplify the denominator by reducing the number of terms and see where it leads.